# I have an equation like ax + by + cz = 0, where a, b, c are constants, I need to find x, y, z

Tags: vector-analysis, problem-solving

I have an equation like $a_ry_1 + b_ry_2 + c_ry_3 = 0$, where $a_r, b_r, c_r$ are constants, I need to find $y_1, y_2, y_3$ where $\hat{y} = y_1 \hat{r} + y_2 \hat{t} + y_3 \hat{n}$ and $\hat{x} = a_r \hat{r} + a_t \hat{t} + a_n \hat{n}$

Earlier I did the following problem,

$$\hat{y}\cdot \hat{x} = 0$$
or, $$(y_1\hat{r} + y_2\hat{t}) \cdot (a_r \hat{r} + a_t \hat{t}) = 0$$
or, $$y_1 a_r + y_2 a_t = 0$$
or, $$y_1 a_r = - y_2 a_t$$
So we can write $$y_1 = - a_t$$ and $$y_2 = a_r$$ where $\hat{x} = a_r \hat{r} + a_t \hat{t}$

can I apply this way to find the current 3D problem (that I explained in the first paragraph) to find the values of $y_1, y_2, y_3$. How should I find those values. I request any suggestions.

Thanks a lot!